# Iterating through URLs with python to scrape similar tables

Tags: python, url, iteration, beautifulsoup

I'm able to scrape a table on the target URL, yet when I try to iterate through the rest of the pages I get -
    TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

there are 17 pages so I've set a var (n) to the max. and used a for loop to get to the successive pages. The code works if the iteration component is commented out. Could the be a define loop to make the code more efficient?

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

n = 17
base_url = 'http://www.lowfloat.com/'
for i in range(1, n+1):
    if (i == 1):
        response = urlopen(base_url)
    response = urlopen(base_url + "all/" %i)
html = response
print (html.response)
#html = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'stocks'})

def target_row(tag):
    is_row = len(tag.findAll('td')) > 5
    row_name = tag.name == 'tr'
    return is_row and row_name
rows = table.findAll(target_row)
rows = rows[1:]

for row in rows:
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    ticker = cells[0].get_text()
    print "ticker " + ticker
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to use the % to pass the variable:

```
response = urlopen(base_url + "all/" %i)
```

It should be:

```
response = urlopen(base_url + "all/" + str(i))
```

Also I didnt get why use this if in the first for...

Comment: This is the error switching % to + - TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: ...and the 'if' is to grab data from the first page.